# CoreData one to one relationship

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data, nsarraycontroller

I am creating a simple application that has three entities. To simplify I call them A, B and C. Between A and B there is one-to-many relationship, while between B and C there is one to one relationship. What I want to obtain is that I can greare an object A to B which connect multiple objects, but each object B there must be only one object C. The C object is to be created automatically when creating the object B.
How can I do?

Comment: If B and C are one-to-one and are both always required as a pair, why bother making them different entities?

Comment: I'm stupid, I had not thought of that. Thank you!

Comment: Not stupid...there could be reasons, such as (slightly!) more efficient access if something only used the C properties.  But it was a question that seemed worth asking.

Comment: and it does help keep your object lean!

Comment: @Daij-Djan  Keeping an object "lean" should be a technique rather than a goal, though.  Assuming simplicity is the goal, then "lean" objects may help or they may lead to unnecessarily-complicated object relationships.

Comment: I deleted the entity C, and I connected the textfield to arraycontroller B, but does not work. If I remove the formatting textfield the application starts, but the textfield displays (0). What is wrong?

Comment: You should provide some details. It's quite difficult to understand what is going on.